# How to store results of dynamic SQL into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

is there a way to store the results of an exec statement in a varchar?

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)
DECLARE @ExecStatement varchar(max)
DECLARE @PromotionXML varchar(max) 

SET @TableName = 'Feeds'

Set @ExecStatement = (
'
SET @PromotionXML = (
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ' + @TableName + ' for xml auto, elements 
    )'
)


exec @ExecStatement


select @PromotionXML
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `sp_executesql`, not `EXEC`, since you need to treat the inner variable as an output parameter (which you can't do with `EXEC`). Also all of these parameters should be `NVARCHAR`, not `VARCHAR` (though I'm curious why you aren't returning the xml as `XML`).

```
DECLARE 
    @TableName NVARCHAR(512),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @TableName = N'dbo.Feeds';

SET @sql = N'SELECT @xml = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), (
    SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS));';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@xml NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @xml OUTPUT;

SELECT @xml;
```